# Merge rows of data from two 2D arrays (each with a shared and a unique column) based on the shared column value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge, grouping

I have two arrays which must be merged together on the `dt_date` column and I need to declare `subscribers` and `unsubscribers` in all rows in the result.

```
$array1 = [
    ['subscribers' => 2, 'dt_date' => '2014-02-27'],
    ['subscribers' => 2, 'dt_date' => '2014-02-25'],
    ['subscribers' => 1, 'dt_date' => '2014-02-07']
];
$array2 = [
    ['unsubscribers' => 1, 'dt_date' => '2014-02-27'],
    ['unsubscribers' => 1, 'dt_date' => '2014-02-01']
];
```

I need to create an array like as follows from the two arrays.

```
[
    ['subscribers' => 2, 'unsubscribers' => 1, 'dt_date' => '2014-02-27'],
    ['subscribers' => 2, 'unsubscribers' => 0, 'dt_date' => '2014-02-25'],
    ['subscribers' => 1, 'unsubscribers' => 0, 'dt_date' => '2014-02-07'],
    ['subscribers' => 0, 'unsubscribers' => 1, 'dt_date' => '2014-02-01']
]
```

I tried

```
$result = array_merge_recursive($aray1, $array2);
```

AND

```
$result = array_merge(
    $array1, 
    array_udiff(
        $array2,
        $array1, 
        function($array1,$array2){
            return strcmp($array1['dt_date'],$array2['dt_date']);
        }
    )
);
```

But the result was not as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer

```
 $result= array_replace_recursive($array1,$array2);
 foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    if(!isset($value['unsubscribers']))
        $result[$key]['unsubscribers']=0;
    if(!isset($value['subscribers']))
        $result[$key]['subscribers']=0;
 }
```

Thank you

Comment: This unexplained answer is provably incorrect when the row with `2014-02-27` in the first array is moved to be the third element of the first array.  [Proof](https://3v4l.org/suNjl)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your question can be resolved with some `foreach` stuff, but I've noticed that you're trying to emulate some kind of SQL `JOIN` behavior (with `ON` column as `dt_date`). That's why I've spent some more time and created more common solution.

First, we'll need to re-index our arrays so we could work with them faster:

```
function reindexArray($array, $column)
{
   return array_combine(
                array_map(function($x) use ($column)
                {
                   return $x[$column];
                }, $array),
                $array
   );
}
```

Function above could be easily replaced with [`array_column()`](http://php.net/array_column) call, but I assume you have PHP 5.3, thus you'll need "manual" re-indexing.

Next, join logic:

```
function arrayJoin($array1, $array2, $column, $default=null)
{
   //in PHP 5.5 it's just array_column() call:
   $array1 = reindexArray($array1, $column);
   $array2 = reindexArray($array2, $column);
   $blank1 = array_combine(
                array_keys(current($array1)), 
                array_fill(1, count(current($array1)), $default)
   );
   $blank2 = array_combine(
                array_keys(current($array2)), 
                array_fill(1, count(current($array2)), $default)
   );
   unset($blank1[$column], $blank2[$column]);

   return array_merge(
             array_map(function($x) use ($array1, $blank2)
             {
                return array_merge($array1[$x], $blank2);
             }, array_keys(array_diff_key($array1, $array2))),
             array_map(function($x) use ($array1, $array2)
             {
                return array_merge($array1[$x], $array2[$x]);
             }, array_keys(array_intersect_key($array1, $array2))),
             array_map(function($x) use ($array2, $blank1)
             {
                return array_merge($array2[$x], $blank1);
             }, array_keys(array_diff_key($array2, $array1)))
   );
}
```

-as you can see, you'll also need to decide what to do with non-set keys for each joined array. `$default` will fill that values for you. Therefore, your question would be resolved via:

```
$result = arrayJoin($array1, $array2, 'dt_date', 0);
```

-check this [demo](http://3v4l.org/lUAeN).

However, if your original array is derived from some SQL database, much better thing would be to place `JOIN` logic there - because intention of DB is to store data & select it properly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Merge the two arrays and loop over them.
2. Assign temporary first level keys as you push data into the result array so that you can swiftly identify related subsequently encountered rows.
3. If the date hasn't been encountered before, merge the row's data with the default row so that all expected elements are represented.
4. If a given date is encountered after the first time, merge the stored row with the new row so that the new row's data overwrites the default value.
5. When finished iterating, re-index the result array with `array_values()` (this removes the temporary first level keys).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/fUaaJ))

```
$result = [];
$default = array_fill_keys(['subscribers', 'unsubscribers'], 0);
foreach (array_merge($array1, $array2) as $row) {
    $result[$row['dt_date']] = array_merge($result[$row['dt_date']] ?? $default, $row);
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```

---

The functional-style equivalent: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/6rUeW))

```
$default = array_fill_keys(['subscribers', 'unsubscribers'], 0);
var_export(
    array_values(
        array_reduce(
            array_merge($array1, $array2),
            function($result, $row) use($default) {
                $result[$row['dt_date']] = array_merge($result[$row['dt_date']] ?? $default, $row);
                return $result;
            }
        )        
    )
);
```